# Renaming the path for asset_url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the WickedPDF gem and it does not properly render images within PDF files unless the URL to the image is pointing to `http://` instead of `https://`. Since my rails application uses HTTPS, I am trying to figure out how to manipulate `asset_url` to point to `http://localhost` rather than `https://path-to-my-site/asset/image.png`.

Is there currently any way to do this with `asset_url`?

Comment: Please share what version of `rails`, `ruby` and `wickedpdf` you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge this is an old issue, and should easily be solved by using a more recent version of `wkhtmltopdf-binary`?

See the link to an issue from 2014: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/344

In the issue they mention the `wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge` gem, however when I upgraded to it I had a lot of weird cosmetic changes.

I opted to use the

```
gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku"
```

even though I do not deploy on heroku but on a ubuntu 18.04 machine.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up removing `wkhtmltopdf` from the Gemfile and installing the binary itself. Looks like we're back in action! Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @nathanvda, I tried using that gem, but it doesn't seem to want to do the trick. Rails fail with a `RuntimeError: Location of wkhtmltopdf unknown` error. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Which gem are you now using? (I mention three different gems). Did you install wkhtmltopdf? (are you able to install it on your deployment server?)

Comment: Seems to be working fine on the development server and the whtmltopdf binary version is the exact same. So strange!!

Comment: Mmmm could it have something to do with permissions? Or are the gems in `:development` group (and thus not installed on the server). Did you install wkhtmltopdf on the server too? I had o.a. a problem with missing supporting libraries.

Comment: Hi @nathanvda. Figured out that part but haven't figured out a solution just yet. This is actually fixed, but apparently it's the because the working version is using `render_to_string` which converts `asset_url` into `http://`, whereas including the Rails URL helpers and using `render` doesn't fully resolve the `asset_url` paths